# asp.net button postbackurl call from every button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

In an asp.net forms website I have a button which has a postpack url:

```
mailBUtton.PostBackUrl = "mailto:..."
```

As expected a click on the button opens the local e-mail software, but If an other button on the page is clicked after the mailButton was clicked, the onClick event of the second button is ignored and instead of the onClick event, the PostBackUrl of the mailButton is called.
What is the reason for these behavior?

This is the mailButton:

```
<asp:Button ID="mailButton" runat="server" Text="Neuer Beitrag" ></asp:Button>
```

and this the second button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSpeichern" runat="server" Text="Speichern" OnClick="btnSpeichern_Click"/>
```

and this the event in the code behind:

```
protected void btnSpeichern_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    speichern(false);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the buttons on the .aspx page and any event wiring done in the code behind? All we have so far is one line of code that works as you intended...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_postbackurl.asp) the `PostBackUrl` of a button is

> A string specifying the URL of the page to post to. Default is an empty string, this causes the page to post back to itself

So when you click the `mailButton` you're setting the pages PostBackUrl to `mailto:...`. By clicking on the second button a postback is performed which now calls the `mailto:` url instead of the original one, where also is no `btnSpeichern_Click` method.

Instead of using a button and `PostBackUrl` you could do the following:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="mailto:abc@abc.com" Text="abc@abc.com"></asp:HyperLink>
```

If you want your link to appear like a button, you can do that in your css.

[Here](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Different-ways-to-create-mailto-link---ASP.Net.aspx) are some more approaches of using `mailto`.